# Android thread and getText() inside for loop not working?

Tags: android, multithreading, textview, thread-sleep

I want to print a single word at a time in textView and then using sleep and then next word.
but it int'n working.. need help.

```
    String s = MainActivity.check;// String check defined in mainactivity this is second
    String[] words = s.split(" ");
    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    for(int i=0;i<words.length; i++ ){
        et.setText(words[i]);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
```

above output only last word in textView

Answer (score 1):

You are setting th text new on each iteration. Try et.setText(et.getText() + words[i]);
This takes the text that is already in the TextView then appends the new word.

Comment: ask 'i' to be final and hence printing only one word

Answer (score 0):

Try using handler instead:

```
for(int i=0;i<words.length; i++ ){
   final int j = i;
   String text = words[j];
   new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            et.setText(text);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: same problem.asks text to be final and hence printing last word in words[]

Answer (score 0):

Any updates to the UI in an Android application must happen in the UI thread. If you spawn a thread to do work in the background you must marshal the results back to the UI thread before you touch a View.

You must use Handler class to do so...

```
public EditText et;
Handler handler;
oncreate(..) {
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    et = new EditText(context);
    Thread t =new Thread(){
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    et.setText("test");
                }
            });
        }
    }};
    t.start();
}
```

Comment: this is not printing all the words stored in words[] rather only "test".

Answer (score 0):

ok , Here is your answer :

```
int i = 0;
Handler handler = new Handler();

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                textView.setText(""+i);
                i++;
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        }, 1000);
```